# Django - template filter tag to change value of a variable for every 'x' th iteration in a for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

in views.py

```
def index(request):
    all_user = Manvi_User.objects.all()
    ordering = all_user.order_by('dob')

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'ordering': ordering})
```

in My tag.py

```
@register.assignment_tag

    def year():

    return "2017"
```

In my index.html

```
{% year as years %}
    {% for Manvi_User in ordering %}

    <li>{{ Manvi_User.first_name }}</li>
    {{years}}
    {{ Manvi_User.dob}}


    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
    {{ years = years+1}}

    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```

I get problem at

years = years +1

I want to display starting first 3 name with year 2017 then 3 name with year 2018 and next 3 name should be with year 2019

Comment: Please be clear of what is working, what is not working, any errors etc

Comment: years = years +1 is not workin

Comment: You cannot perform mathematical operations in django templates. What is the purpose of your assignment_tag? It returns the same string "2017" always

Comment: Is there any other way i can do that?

Comment: {{year|add:1}}  try this way, also you might need to send view code, not getting exactly you need, but solutions are there for every situation.

Comment: i added my view code

Comment: {{year|add:1}} work but it's come at only 3

Comment: @John where that years comes from into template? as there's no render object passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the forloop counter value to a custom template filter tag, perform your calculations there and then return it.
Although, it's best to keep logical code restricted to the view - you should see if there is any way to move this piece of code to your view

my_tag.py,

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def calculate_year(year, loop_counter):
    try:
        year = int(year)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    else:
        return str(year + (loop_counter//3))  # This will work on python 2.x and 3.x
        #return str(year + (loop_counter/3))  # This will not work on python 3.x
```

in your template,

```
{% load my_tag %}

<!-- Some code inside your forloop -->

{{year|calculate_year:forloop.counter}}
```